# Comparing the degree of dehydration

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am confused regarding the following problem  which asks to arrange the given compounds in decreasing order of their degree of dehydration

[image]

My attempt at the solution:
I tried to find out the products and compare their stability:
[image]

Now in the first case product is conjugated. So I think it is the most stable.
The second one has 6 alpha hydrogen while the third one has only 3 alpha hydrogen.
Hence order should be 1>2>3
But the answer given is 1>3>2

2. My second confusion is whether such alpha-hydroxy ketones will follow the E1 or E2 dehydration process. I thought that E1 elimination won't be favourable cause the positive charge next to the keto group will be destabilised. Is it correct?

Comment: What is "decreasing degree of dehydration"? Do you mean rate?

Comment: Yes in other words "the rate or ease of dehydration"

Comment: @Arpan For considering rate of these reactions you have to compare the rate of intermediate steps, and not consider the thermodynamic stability of the final products. Here, rather than formation of carbocation you should consider, the relative rate of abstracting the acidic hydrogen. Since in 1 the hydrogens are acidic due to strong inductive effect(negative) thus the rate for $1st$ is highest, and $2nd$ has the least acidic hydrogens thus $1>3>2$

Comment: @Rishi Thanks. I got your logic.Are we doing so(not comparing the carbocation stability) cause this process does not follow E1 pathway?

Comment: As a general rule in organic chemistry problems, rate (a kinetic concept) should only be tied to thermodynamics by the appropriate application of the Hammond Postulate.